# How to install flatpak build dependencies?

Tags: flatpak

Trying to build a flatpak for my app, but it needs `inkscape` in order to build the app (obviously not a dependency of the app at runtime, just a build time).  `inkscape` is installed on the host system, but I understand that `flatpak-builder` cannot run commands from the host.  Can I depend on https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.inkscape.Inkscape somehow?  Or do I have to build all of Inkscape from source just to build my app?

Comment: If it’s just a build dependency, you could just add a binary build into the sources and use that.

Comment: As to depending on another Flatpak package… tricky. You’d have to depend on a concrete commit not to violate build reproducibility, and AFAIK Flathub only stores the last two versions. Something like this isn’t possible with the current infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Any flatpak has files that are available from the filesystem, so you can link to the inkscape flatpak from builder.  It may actually link libraries automatically if the Inkscape flatpak is intended to be a runtime, but if not, point builder to the libraries contained in `/var/lib/flatpak/app/org.inkscape.Inkscape/x86_64/stable/active/files/lib`, and hopefully it'll have what you're looking for.

Definitely a lot easier than a package manager to clean up afterward if you don't want to keep the libraries when you're done.